# How to run mongo --eval?

Tags: javascript, command-line, mongodb, evaluate

I run mongo --help  and it has an options for evaluate javascript.

```
mongo --eval  arg
```

However, I haven't found any example of how to use it. I try to run it but with no success.  anyone know how to do it?

the reason is that, I want to delete a collection through command line ( so that I can reuse the code and put it into shell script).  I know I can write another nodejs and call the db to run it.. but instead of 20 lines of code, it would be nice if there is a solution with only few lines and be faster. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be:

```
mongo <server>:<port>/<database> --eval "db.<some_collection>.drop();"
```

Or if you want to do something in more lines you can call a file (must end with `.js`):

```
mongo <server>:<port>/<database> some_instructions.js
```