# Execute load(file) in mongodb container from outside

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have file.js in a volume of an docker container (mongo:latest). I execute it by connecting to the container, mongo, load(..../file.js).
Is it possible to execute the file with **one command from outside the container**?
Something like:
`docker exec -it mongo_1 mongo --username name --password pw && load('...file.js')`

Comment: As shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959313/5418336 there is no need to "load". Just add the Path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to execute in the mongo DB Container unless JS runtime is available in that container, Or you can build your own Custom image that has Mongo DB and JS runtime available using a docker file

Comment: I have the container (mongo:latest) up and I can execute the file inside the container. I just want to start the execution from outside.

Comment: In that case, try using docker-compose it is easier to orchestrate form outside the container.